# Grab the closest date in future from current date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am editing this post to give a better description of my problem.
As of time of posting, todays current date is 25/11/2020. So my current query looks like this, I have excluded some joins and tried to condense it

```
SELECT SCHEDULES.START_DTTM as [ApptDate],SERVICE_POINTS.CODE AS [DepartmentCode]
FROM LIST
JOIN SCHEDULES ON LIST.L_REFNO = SCHEDULES.L_REFNO
JOIN SERVICE_POINTS ON SCHEDULES.S_REFNO = SERVICE_POINTS.S_REFNO
WHERE SERVICE_POINTS.CODE = 'ABC'
AND convert(varchar(10), SCHEDULES.START_DTTM, 102)  >= convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 102)
ORDER by SCHEDULES.START_DTTM
```

When I run this query it will output everything greater than or equal to today as below

```
ApptDate    DepartmentCode
2020-11-25 08:00:00.000 ABD
2020-11-25 09:00:00.000 ABC
2020-11-25 10:00:00.000 ABC
2020-11-25 12:00:00.000 ABC
2020-11-25 14:00:00.000 ABC
2020-11-26 08:00:00.000 ABC
2020-11-26 10:00:00.000 ABC
2020-11-26 12:00:00.000 ABC
2020-11-26 14:00:00.000 ABC
2020-11-27 08:00:00.000 ABC
2020-11-27 10:00:00.000 ABC
2020-11-27 12:00:00.000 ABC
2020-11-30 08:00:00.000 ABC
2020-11-30 10:00:00.000 ABC
2020-11-30 12:00:00.000 ABC
```

The desired output I want is, if the query is run today (25/11/2020) to return,

```
2020-11-25 08:00:00.000 ABD
2020-11-25 09:00:00.000 ABC
2020-11-25 10:00:00.000 ABC
2020-11-25 12:00:00.000 ABC
2020-11-25 14:00:00.000 ABC
```

If it is run tomorrow, (26/11/20202)

```
2020-11-26 08:00:00.000 ABC
2020-11-26 10:00:00.000 ABC
2020-11-26 12:00:00.000 ABC
2020-11-26 14:00:00.000 ABC
```

Also just to show that its not the next, it's the closest future date I want, if its run on the 28/11/2020 to return,

```
2020-11-30 08:00:00.000 ABC
2020-11-30 10:00:00.000 ABC
2020-11-30 12:00:00.000 ABC
```

Could someone still help with this? How do I modify my existing query to get this working? Again appreciate any help on this.

Comment: I'm confused.  Is the first table showing the desired output (as you state) or is that your input?  Are you looking for just the rows that have a date (not time) value matching today?

Comment: This is what I have so far select  SCHEDULES.START_DTTM from schedules
where convert(varchar(10), SCHEDULES.START_DTTM, 102)  >= convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 102)
order by SCHEDULES.START_DTTM

Comment: The first table is showing my current output, the second table is showing my desired output if the query is executed today(because it returns the closest rows for going forward from today if that makes sense

Comment: [edit] any addition info directly into your question.

Comment: You say you want "the closet rows from the current date."  Closest how many rows?  One of your outputs has 5 rows and the other has 4 rows.  Current date, or current datetime?  Do you mean, "the rows within 12 hours of the current datetime"?  The closest 4 rows to the current datetime?  The rows from today?

Comment: @dougp -- Grab the closest date in future, so it would be all rows that are next or equal to current date/day

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want rows whose date is today. Assuming a data structure like `mytable(mycol)`, you can use:

```
select *
from mytable
where mycol >= convert(date, getdate()) 
  and mycol <  dateadd(day, 1, convert(date, getdate()))
order by mycol
```

You might be tempted to shorten the `where` clause to:

```
where convert(date, mycol) = convert(date, getdate())
```

This works, but is less efficient, because it cannot take advantage of an index on `mycol`, unlike the first query, that does direct filtering.

---

**Edit**

If you want rows whose date part is closest to the current date, even if the dates are not the same, one alternative uses window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, 
        rank() over(order by abs(datediff(day, mycol, getdate()))) rn
    from mytable
) t
where rn = 1
order by mycol
```

Or, if you don't care about the ordering of the rows in the resultset, we can use `with ties`:

```
select top (1) with ties *
from mytable
order by rank() over(order by abs(datediff(day, mycol, getdate())))
```

Comment: I probably didnt explain it correctly, so its not today or tomorrow but the next nearest date from the current date I am looking for, so the date could be two or three days time but the query when executed will only return the rows that are closest

Comment: OK so I have tried this and it is still not working, it doesnt return the closest from the current date if that makes sense. any other suggestions are highly welcome @GMB

Comment: ok so I have updated the description of my problem, is it still possible to do this from my existing code?

Answer (score 0):

To grab the closest dates from today, in either direction, you first need to figure out what that date *is*.

```sql
-- Convert dates to yyyy-mm-dd for easy comparison and gathering
-- Grab the closest date REGARDLESS of whether in past or future 
select * 
from test 
where convert(varchar, col1, 23) = (select top 1 convert(varchar, col1, 23) 
                                    from test 
                                    order by abs(datediff(day, col1, getdate())) ASC 
                                    );
```

Please note that the `abs` function means it will display the nearest results in the *past*, as well, if those happen to be the closest. If you don't want that functionality, then throw it into the where clause to ensure it doesn't happen.

```sql
-- Grab the closest date in future 
select * 
from test 
where convert(varchar, col1, 23) = (select top 1 convert(varchar, col1, 23) 
                                    from test 
                                    where datediff(day, col1, getdate()) <= 0
                                    order by abs(datediff(day, col1, getdate())) ASC 
                                    );
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0cc96e6308436a97ff4288df20c363b9)

### EDIT:

I forget about index optimization, and I was rightly called out for a complete lack of index usability in the code I provided (though, that presumes the user has an index on this table :P ).

@GMB's and @DaleK's both appear to answer your problem, OP, but GMB's looks easier to incorporate into your existing code and does so without calling the original table twice, so incorporating their answer into your query would look similar to:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (     

    /*  your query goes in this section*/
    SELECT 
         SCHEDULES.START_DTTM as [ApptDate],
         SERVICE_POINTS.CODE AS [DepartmentCode],
         daterank = rank() over(order by abs(datediff(day, SCHEDULES.START_DTTM, getdate()))) /* this ranks which dates are closest to today */
    FROM LIST
    JOIN SCHEDULES      ON LIST.L_REFNO = SCHEDULES.L_REFNO
    JOIN SERVICE_POINTS     ON SCHEDULES.S_REFNO = SERVICE_POINTS.S_REFNO
    WHERE SERVICE_POINTS.CODE = 'ABC'
        and datediff(day, SCHEDULES.START_DTTM, getdate()) <= 0 /* in the future*/

) myNewTable
WHERE daterank = 1 /* this is the magic that grabs only the closest to today */     
ORDER by START_DTTM
```

Comment: Converting dates to a varchar for conversion is a serious **no no** - it immediately makes the query un-sargable and adds issues of format. Compare dates as dates or date ranges.

Comment: @CoffeeNeedCoffee This is exactly what I am looking for 'Grab the closest date in future' but I am trying to incorporate your code into my code and still trying to get it working. I have lots of other tables joined on my main query.

Comment: @DaleK  is there a better way to do it? The logic above is definelty what I am looking for

Comment: @Conger88 although it seems to me that GMB's answer works perfectly also?

Comment: @DaleK how do i incorporate GMBs solution into my existing code, I cant seem to get working :(

Comment: @Conger88 I edited my answer to give you a sample of how to incorporate GMB's better into your query. If it works, you should upvote and accept GMB's answer. Basically, you're going to throw your entire query into the inner SELECT statement, then you'll add the ```rank()``` statement he provided to sort your dates properly, add a WHERE statement on the inside to look into the future, and the WHERE statement on the outside to only grab the closest date.

Answer (score 0):

Building on @CoffeeNeedCoffee's answer but using a sargable query gives the following which essentially builds a date range consisting of a single day in the future, the first day with a record.

Being sargable means the query engine can make use of indexes which is an important performance consideration unless you want a complete table scan every time you run the query.

```
declare @Test table (col1 datetime);

insert into @Test (col1)
values
('2020-11-25 08:00:00.000'),
('2020-11-25 09:00:00.000'),
('2020-11-25 10:00:00.000'),
('2020-11-25 12:00:00.000'),
('2020-11-25 14:00:00.000'),
('2020-11-26 14:00:00.000');

select T.col1 
from @Test T
cross join (  
    select top 1 convert(date,T1.col1) StartDateRange, dateadd(day, 1, convert(date,T1.col1)) EndDateRange
    from @Test T1
    where datediff(day, T1.col1, getdate()) <= 0
    order by abs(datediff(day, T1.col1, getdate())) asc
) X
where T.col1 >= X.StartDateRange and T.col1 < X.EndDateRange;
```

Comment: hi @DaleK i have updated my question description with better exampels and my code to date. I am still looking for an answer on it if you can help at all.

Answer (score -1):

```
select ApptDate
, DepartmentCode
from mytable
where convert(date, ApptDate) = (
    select min(convert(date, ApptDate))
    from mytable
    where convert(date, ApptDate) >= convert(date, getdate())
  )
order by ApptDate
```

Comment: I probably didnt explain it correctly, so its not today or tomorrow but the next nearest date from the current date I am looking for, so the date could be two or three days time but the query when executed will only return the rows that are closest. so I am not sure if the above will work?

Comment: Actually applogies I think thats working!! :) two seconds

Comment: OK so I have tried this and it is still not working, it doesnt return the closest from the current date if that makes sense. any other suggestions are highly welcome

Comment: @Conger88 please demonstrate how it doesn't work - based on the sample data provided it does work, so you need to clarify with sample data a situation where it doesn't work.

Comment: @DaleK ok so it is returning the current dates only but this query would not work for finding future closer dates if that makes sense. I basically just want to return only the closest dates/rows/entries from a query when executed from the current date. So if the table column had dates for next year only and it was executed today it would only return those rows.

Comment: @Conger88 no that doesn't make sense... and is definitely not clear from your question. Are you saying you want to retrieve all the records from a single day, and that day is either today, or the closest day after today? If so please update your question to clarify this point, and provide suitable sample data.